# How to convert bytes to integer in php like python libnum s2n function

Tags: python, php, ascii

I Want To Convert Text To Number Like in Python.
My Python Code:

```
from libnum import *
print(s2n("Text"))
# Output: 1415936116
print(s2n("\x31\x34\x31\x35\x39\x33\x36\x31\x31\x36"))
# Output: 1415936116
```

This is my php code. I went this far:

```
$String = "Text";
$Bytes = "";

$Length = strlen($String);
for ($i=0; $i<$Length; $i++) {
    $Bytes .= "\x".(string)dechex(mb_ord($String[$i]));
}

echo $Bytes;
// Output: \x31\x34\x31\x35\x39\x33\x36\x31\x31\x36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert strings to an integer using `hexdec(bin2hex($string));`

I fiddled around trying to figure out how to turn the packed hex string into an integer but couldn't figure out how to return the same integer as the string.

Comment: This does work. It returns 1415936116. I ran the PHP code in the question, and the outcome was: `\x54\x65\x78\x74`, which makes sense. The `\x31\x34\x31\x35\x39\x33\x36\x31\x31\x36` byte sequence make no sense. It is the reason I didn't try to answer this question.